# Is there a way to use foreign language characters in my application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, localization

I'm working on a windows forms application in Visual Studio 2010 C++, and I wish to distribute this application once I"m done with it. I figured writing it in my own language, but I have characters such as these -> { ă, ş, ţ } amongst many more. I can't use them in elements such as labels, etc without receiving errors.

Is there any work around this? I've seen C++ applications written in my native language with those characters but I can't figure it out.

Comment: How did you try it? What errors are you receiving? This should be straightforward.

Comment: I write int ă = 1; and it compiled with no error with VC++2010.

Comment: @BlueWanderer, try putting one of those characters as a label or in a button text, it gives a dialog box saying "Some unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current codepage"

Comment: Um... label. I thought it was label in the code. That dialog just tell you the source file will be saved in utf8 format, nothing more. But this should only happen when the character you use doesn't match the system's current locale. Your system locale is not set to your native language?

Comment: This is the exact error: error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131195) : Custom attributes are not consistent: (0x0c000024).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use localization for that. I see you are using C++ with Windows forms so you must be using .Net with C++/Cli.
In that case you can start with ["How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for Windows Forms Globalization"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh.aspx) and ["Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Those are in VB/C# but you should have no trouble converting them to C++/Cli.

Comment: “Windows Forms” != “WinForms”! But using C++/CLI + WinForms is probably the best solution here so +1.

Answer (score -1):

The dialog you get is not prompting you an error. Click OK and the source file will be saved in UTF8 format that can fit any locale.

And beware that you better not use multi-byte character set, or you will see funny characters on your buttons or labels or so.